# Difference between call signature and function type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to understand why we have different syntax for call signatures and for function types. Consider the following code:

```
interface MyInterface {
   // This is call signature
   // It is used inside object type, function expression, function declaration, etc...
    (x:number, y:number):number; 
}

var myOne : MyInterface = (x,y) => x + y;
            // vv this is function type
var myTwo : (x:number, y:number)=>number = (x,y) => x + y; 
// function type is used in function type literal
```

In this code `myOne` and `myTwo` variables effectively the same. They are (as far as I can see) of the very same type, just defined differently.

Now when we are using interface for defining them we use *call signature* that looks like this:

```
(x:number, y:number):number
```

When we are not using interface we use *function type literal*:

```
(x:number, y:number)=>number
```

Both express the same thing, names and types of parameters and types of the return type. I would like to know, why do we need two different yet so similar ways to write the same thing in typescript?

Comment: Additionally we have *arrow function expressions* which have nothing to do either with *call signature* or with *function type literal* but they also contain the arrow `=>`. This makes the whole thing even more confusing for me.

Comment: `function type literal` should be changed to its official terminology which is `function type expression`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

They are exactly the same.

> why do we need two different yet so similar ways to write the same thing in typescript

The `(x:number, y:number)=>number` signature is useful as a `property` annotation :

```
interface MyInterface {
    (x:number, y:string):string;   
    someProperty: (x:number, y:number)=>number;
}
```

Which is similar to your:

```
var myTwo : (x:number, y:number)=>number
```

Just a shorthand for a **verbose** :

```
var myTwo : {(x:number, y:number):number}
```

So you can see the simplicity of `()=>`.

### Also

One thing to note is that a *function* signature allows *overloading*:

```
var myTwo : {
    (x:number, y:number):number;
    (x:number):string;
}
```

Which is not supported for a `property` annotation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! When you put it this way it does make sense.

Comment: I really wish `someProperty: (x:number, y:number):number;` was supported but someone made that choice ... and I've made my peace with it. Might have got them out of a tricky disambiguation

Comment: @basarat If we build a function that accepts that MyInterface type variable, how can we refer to the function inside it( the (x:number, y:string):string; ) in the function?

Comment: Just adding on top of the @basarat's answer: 
It's possible to add a property annotation using similar looking type to call signature as well.
`
interface MyInterface {
    (x:number, y:string):string;   
    someProperty(x:number, y:number): number;
}
`

In this example, MyInterface is a function type as well as it has object `someProperty`.

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that Functions in TypeScript are first class citizens, which are treated as types just like any other types (String, Array, Number, etc.).