# function definition syntax confuse in Typescript

Tags: typescript

All:

**[UPDATE]** I figure that out: One post in SO explain this: 
[In TypeScript how do I declare an array of functions that accept a string and return a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706161/in-typescript-how-do-i-declare-an-array-of-functions-that-accept-a-string-and-re)
it turns out:

> A function type literal of the form
>
> ( ParamList ) => ReturnType
>
> is exactly equivalent to the object type literal
>
> { ( ParamList ) : ReturnType }

**So**, Colon`:` with Bracket`{}`  **<=>** Arrow `=>`

---

I am pretty new to Typescript, there is one example confuses me with its syntax:

```
var sayHello: (input: string) : string = function (s: string) {
    return "Hello " + s;
}
var stringUtils: { (input: string): string; }[];
stringUtils.push(sayHello);
```

Could anyone help to give a little explanation what this code do? Especially what the first part definition does?

```
var sayHello: (input: string) : string = function (s: string) {
    return "Hello " + s;
}
```

The example says sayHello is a function variable, but when I run it,  I got "=>" expected error, does this mean this syntax belong to old typescript but not exist now?

Thanks

Comment: I'm actually not even sure that's valid TypeScript...? It doesn't seem to work when I paste it here: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground

Comment: @Katana314 Thanks, neither on my side, so basically it could be a typo?

Comment: Could this be the intention? `var sayHello: (input: string) => string = function (s: string) {
    return "Hello " + s;
}`. It would be good to get confirmation before delving into explanation

Comment: @Katana314 not sure, but I guess so. This is from a book called "Typescript Revealed"(Pub. 2013), it uses this example to show why we need interface

Comment: If the book you're reading keeps having syntax errors in it, you should find a different book...?

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh Thanks, will do later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could anyone help to give a little explanation what this code do? Especially what the first part definition does
>   `var sayHello: (input: string) : string = function (s: string) {`

Should be:

```
var sayHello: (input: string) => string = function (s: string) {
```

We are saying that `sayHello` is a function that takes a string and returns a string `: (input: string) => string` . Then we assign it to such a function `= function (s: string) {`

Comment: Thanks, I am reading your suggested gitbook. One thing gets me confused is the definition of interface, I wonder how to define an interface with a string member and a function member with one string parameter and return string?

Comment: I read from this post:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2013/01/24/interfaces-walkthrough.aspx   when specify a function inside a interface, I am not sure why it can use colon this time? (in Basic section: it use interface Greetable {
    greet(message: string): void;
}
)

Comment: @Kuan that difference is covered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32043487/difference-between-call-signature-and-function-type/32043715#32043715 Its just a property shorthand