# Does TypeScript Interface have anonymous and named function?

Tags: typescript

I think Interface rarely have both anonymous and named function. Is this right?

TypeScript compiler allows interface to have both anonymous and named function.

```
// no error
interface Foo {
  (x: number, y: number): number; // anonymous
  namedMethod: (z: string, w: string) => string; // named
}
```

But it seems unavailable.

```
// badProp is not assignable
const foo1 : Foo = {
  badProp(x: number, y: number) { return 1 },
  namedMethod(a: string, b: string) { return 'str'; }
}

// syntax error
const foo2 : Foo = {
  (x: number, y: number) { return 1 },
  namedMethod(a: string, b: string) { return 'str'; }
}
```

using `any` type, it works.

```
const temp: any = function (x: number, y: number) { return 1 };
temp.namedMethod = function (a: string, b: string) { return 'str'; }
const foo3: Foo = temp;
```

Though using both is Technically possible, Interface rarely have both anonymous and named function.
Is this right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32043487/difference-between-call-signature-and-function-type might be a little different, but it is useful

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An *"unnamed"* member in a TypeScript interface does not refer to an anonymous member, but declares the function signature of the interfaced class itself, [as described in this section of the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#function-types).

For example:

```js
/**
 * Interface for function that takes two numbers as arguments, and returns
 * a number.
**/
interface TwoNumberFunction {
    (x: number, y: number): number,
}

// simple function: adds two numbers
function add(x: number, y: number): number {
    return x + y;
}

// 'add' is a function that takes two numbers and returns a
// number, so it matches the interface's requirements:
const func: TwoNumberFunction = add;
func(1, 2); // = 3
```

Answer (score 8):

TypeScript allows interfaces to have hybrid types, i.e. interfaces can have a combination of properties, function declarations, indexer and methods. This flexibility is allowed to get aligned with JavaScript dynamic nature.

```
interface Foo {
    (x: number, y: number): number; // anonymous
    namedMethod: (z: string, w: string) => string; // named
    randomNumber: number
}

const foo2 = ((x: number, y: number) => x+ y + 1) as Foo;
foo2.namedMethod = (z: string, w: string) => z;
foo2.randomNumber = 4
console.log(foo2(1, 3)); // prints 5
console.log(foo2.namedMethod('hello', 'world')); // prints 'hello'
console.log(foo2.randomNumber); // prints 4
```

Watch this video to know [what is hybrid types in typescript?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYAq1A4BsuI)

Answer (score 2):

there is **two way** to write `Function types`.
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#334-function-types is helpful.

### 1. call signatures in object type literals.

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#392-call-signatures

```
// call signatures is like this.
(x: number, y: number): number,
```

#### interfaces to declare function types

[spec](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#71-interface-declarations) says that

> Since function and constructor types are just object types containing call and construct signatures, interfaces can be used to declare named function and constructor types.

so I can write this.

```
// interface with call signatures
interface TwoNumberFunctionInterface {
  (x: number, y: number): number,
}
```

### 2. function type literal.

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#388-function-type-literals

```
// function type literal is like this
let a: (x: number, y: number) => number;
```

function type literal is shorthand for an object type containing a single call signature.

```
// object type containing a single call signature
let a: {(x: number, y: number): number};
```